Newbie trying to write a simple script to automate command
Occasionally I have to clean up space by deleting older images and am doing this by manually going into various directories and doing this. I wanted to make a simple script to do this and have created the following (and made it executable with CHMOD)  but get an error;
"bash: snapshot_remove: command not found"
What am I doing wrong pls?
Heres my script;
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/web2py/web2py_apps/snapshots/
cd 1
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 2
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 3
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 4
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 5
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 0
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 7
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 9
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 10
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 11
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd 12
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
cd 13
find -type f -mtime +25 -delete
cd ..
echo ** Snapshot removal Complete **
df
exit

:end

Sorry I should have also added .. I am using Debian Linux accessing using PuTTy

Theoretically, this makes it off-topic on AD. But Unix shells work the same way on Linux and macOS, so the answers are still valid.

If this script is named snapshot_remove you need to execute it as ./snapshot_remove in its parent directory. It has to be prefixed with the directory as the directory will not be in the $PATH by default. bash will not execute scripts in the current directory unless specifically instructed to do so.
echo should quote the output string, otherwise odd stuff gets echoed.
You also have an error in the find command, missing the base directory. It should be
find ./ -type f -mtime +25 -delete

Aside from that, you can simplify your script as follows, assuming you have a fixed list of sub-directories you wish to tidy:
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/web2py/web2py_apps/snapshots/
for subdirectory in 1 2 3 4 5 0 7 9 10 11 12 13 ; do
    find ./$subdirectory -type f -mtime +25 -delete
done
echo '** Snapshot removal Complete **'
df
exit

Note. Ensure you have a good backup, and familiarise yourself with the script. While I've tested the code, I'm not in your environment, so YMMV.

Thanks so much Andy. And thanks for the reminder on the backup. Cheers

find accepts several base directories, so you could replace the loop with find 1 2 3 4 5 0 7 9 10 11 12 13 -type ... (or even find {0..5} 7 {9..13} -type ...).

@nohillside Of course!

Andy's answer is correct AFAICS. I'm adding this answer to provide some alternatives you may want to consider:
There are two aspects to your question: 1) is the PATH aspect wrt the location of your script (snapshot_remove), and 2) is the syntax of the script itself. As I understand your question, and the error message you posted, it seems the primary aspect is re your PATH; i.e. the variable that defines where the system looks to find executable commands you enter.
Let's address the PATH aspect first:
The PATH environment variable is the key to part of your question. PATH determines where the system will look (in what folders) to find the "command" you enter. It appears your script is located in a folder that is not included in your PATH. This would explain your error message:

"bash: snapshot_remove: command not found"

You have two (2) options to resolve this error:

move your script to a folder that is in your PATH, or
modify your PATH environment variable to include the folder containing snapshot_remove

Let's start with Option 1: Move your script :
Open a Terminal, and enter echo $PATH at the prompt to see what it contains. Hopefully, it will contain the folder usr/local/bin. If it does not, there could be any number of reasons why (Apple may have been inconsistent??), but the issue is easily remedied as shown below in the Addendum: How to Modify /etc/paths.
Traditionally, in a Unix-like system setup, the folder usr/local/bin (or perhaps /usr/local) would be the preferred location for locally-sourced executable files - such as your snapshot_remove script.  This location being IAW the "Filesystem Hierarchy Standard". Accordingly, you could place your script in that folder, and forget all of the rest of the business associated with updating your PATH environment variable.
Option 2: Modify your PATH environment variable
The alternative to placing your script in /usr/local/bin is to modify the PATH variable in your environment. I will assume your script is in your Users folder (Users/whoeveryouare). You can add that folder to your PATH variable as a Temporary change, or you can add it as a Permanent change:
Temporary change:
Assuming you're using zsh, do this from Terminal:
path+=/Users/whoeveryouare

# OR...

path+=/Users/whoever/myscripts

Permanent change:
Open your favorite editor, and add the following to .zshrc (or .bashrc if you use bash):
cd /Users/whoever 
nano .zshrc
#
# add one line:

export PATH=/Users/whoever:$PATH

NOTE: It's been reported that Apple does not include a ~/.zshrc file. If that's your case, just create the file yourself & modify it as described above.
Now let's address the "script syntax" aspect:
As I understand your script, you are using find to delete all files in a series of folders that were modified more than 25 hours ago. If I've got your objective correct, then please read on.
find seems a reasonable choice for this objective. I think Andy's answer offers reasonable suggestions that will simplify your script. I'm not very well-placed to address this aspect as I've not used Apple's version of find for many years (I use MacPorts' GNU version of find). But I might suggest something along this line (using -type f, and -mindepth 1 together is perhaps overcautious):
find /home/web2py/web2py_apps/snapshots/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +25 -delete

I'm ignoring your use of /home, which AFAIK doesn't exist in mac OS.
I might also recommend mving the files to a folder in /tmp - instead of -delete (i.e. -execdir mv f /tmp/X). This would give you a chance to reconsider those deletions before making them permanent. In any case, I'd replace -delete with -print to verify things were working correctly in all cases.
And finally, I'd recommend you read this (good & reasonable) explanation on how mtime is interpreted. I believe this explanation applies to the GNU version of find, but I do not know if it also applies to Apple's version (i.e. /usr/bin/find).


ADDENDUM: How to Modify /etc/paths
Open the file /etc/paths in your favorite editor (aka /private/etc/paths). I assume nano is your editor here, but substitute whatever you use in place of that. Also Note: If you do not have sudo set up, you can do that by entering the command sudo visudo in Terminal. Once you're able to use sudo:
sudo nano /etc/paths
#
# add one line to the file:

/usr/local/bin

# save & exit the editor


Just two remarks to /etc/paths: /usr/local/bin is already included in recent versions of macOS, also it‘s better to add user-defined additions as a file to /etc/paths.d/ to make sure an OS update doesn’t overwrite them.

@nohillside: Good points, but: 1) we don't know what version of mac OS the OP is using, 2) could I ask your source for the stmt that etc/paths.d/ is not over-written?

Re 2) practical experience :-). There is a Q&A about this on AD somewhere, not sure it refers to a source though.

Re 1) it‘s included since at least El Capitan (source: AD search), so I would assume it‘s there for 99.9% of the users.

@nohillside: Yeah, I should have been more specific; I was referring to something in Apple's documentation, but this is OK.
